# While call rest api in Javascript (NodeJS) and return response Undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

When i call rest API and  return response it show undefined  but i console.log this response it return

```
var request = require("request");

function initialize() {
  // Setting URL and headers for request
  var options = {
    url: 'http://postalpincode.in/api/pincode/400605',
    json: true
  };
  // Return new promise 
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    // Do async job
    request.get(options, function (err, resp, body) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(JSON.stringify(body));
      }
    })
  })

}

function main() {
  var initializePromise = initialize();
  initializePromise.then(function (result) {
    return result;
  })
}
console.log('', main())
```

But when i console log this response it show output correct

```
var request = require("request");

function initialize() {
  // Setting URL and headers for request
  var options = {
    url: 'http://postalpincode.in/api/pincode/400605',
    json: true
  };
  // Return new promise 
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    // Do async job
    request.get(options, function (err, resp, body) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(JSON.stringify(body));
      }
    })
  })

}

function main() {
  var initializePromise = initialize();
  initializePromise.then(function (result) {
    console.log('', result)
  })
}
console.log('', main())
```

I want When i call rest API and  return response it show correct output

Comment: Use a call back in main or create a promise in main or use async and await. That is asynchronous function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return inside the `then`scope is not returning for the function `main`, but only for the `then`scope of the promise. You need to return the promise like so:

```
function main() {
  var initializePromise = initialize();
  return initializePromise.then(function (result) {
    return result;
  })
}

main().then((result) => console.log('',result));
```

you can't make a sync function call an async method and expect to have get its result.

Answer (score 1):

use `async/await`

```
async function main() {
  var initializePromise = await initialize();
  console.log(initializePromise)
}
```

Comment: While using a async/await it return

`Promise { <pending> }
{"Message":"Number of Post office(s) found: 1","Status":"Success","PostOffice":[{"Name":"Kalwa","Description":"","BranchType":"Sub Post Office","DeliveryStatus":"Delivery","Taluk":"Thane","Circle":"Thane","District":"Thane","Division":"Thane Central","Region":"Mumbai","State":"Maharashtra","Country":"India"}]}`

Comment: print your result using `initializePromise.PostOffice` and see what will print.

Comment: so what ?  i think this one is true answer !

Comment: async/await is just another tool to handle async behaviour. However, op needs a better understanding of how promises and async works.

Comment: While result using `initializePromise.PostOffice`  it will print  `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

My question is, why are you wrapping in a new Promise something that's already from a return type of Promise?

You could just do:

```js
request.get(endpoint, options).then((response) => console.log(response)).catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

Let me know what's the output in that case.

Answer (score 0):

The then resolution of initializePromise method resolves at a later stage when a response is fetched from REST HTTP call i.e. it does not get returned when you call main() method due to the fact it is async. To handle such code, you should either use a callback

```
function main(completionHandler) {
  var initializePromise = initialize();
  initializePromise.then(function (result) {
    completionHandler(result);
  })
}
main((result) => { console.log(result)})
```

or a promise

```
function main() {
    // Return new promise 
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        var initializePromise = initialize();
        initializePromise.then(function (result) {
            resolve(result);
        })
    }
}

main().then(result => console.log(result));
```

Comment: In that case it will go in ` Promise { <pending> }`  then after 1s  print console.log

Answer (score 0):

```
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    // Do async job
    request.get(options, function (err, resp, body) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        try {
          resolve(JSON.stringify(body));
        } catch(e) {
          reject(e);
        }
      }
    })
  })
```

in main function:

```
function main() {
  initialize().then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  }).catch((err) => {
     console.log(err);
     return err;
  })
}
```